# How to choose network interface with node's experimental http2-module?

Tags: node.js, http, http2

Trying to use Node's experimental [http2](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html)-module and want to select the network interface used for outbound connections.

Using the standard http-module in node, this can be done by specifying either the `localAddress`-argument on a connection or a socket as detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602066/how-to-specify-a-network-interface-when-making-net-requests-from-node-js) SO-answer.

Unfortunately, the `localAddress`-argument is nowhere to be found in the http2-docs.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try localAddress option the same way as in http? Since it's experimental, there's a chance that it's still undocumented.

Comment: @estus is right. As per https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_http2_connect_authority_options_listener , `http2.connect` supports `net.connect` options. In other words `localAddress`.

Comment: Missed that 1-liner in the docs. Cheers!